# Using regex in Java to SELECTIVELY find a pattern

Tags: java, regex, twitter, pattern-matching

I have a list of strings (in this case tweets from Twitter). These strings are posted by users, and sometimes reference other specific users. I am using Regular expressions along with Java's String.replaceAll(pattern, replace) method to replace instances of common problems with speech (in this case, repeated consonants), but I need a way to make it ignore any pattern it finds in a username. Username patterns universally match the regex `\b@\S+\b`

So I want to match `y+`, but NOT as a member of anything that would match `\b@\S+\b`

So in `everybodyy @everybodyy everybodyy` I would match `ever(y)bod(yy) @everybodyy ever(y)bod(yy)`

Is this possible, and how do I do it?

Comment: I'm not really sure this can be solved with a simple regexp. My approach would be to find where in the input string the usernames are, then scan only the parts of the string around them.

Comment: Alternately, you could do something like: find matches of `(\b@\S+\b)|(y+)`, then iterate over the matches and determine what to do about them based on whether the capture group `1` or `2` was found. That said, you'll have to use a `Matcher`, not `replaceAll()`.

Comment: The problem is regular expression engines generally do not support variable-length look-behind, which is required to check the `y` is not preceeded by `\b@\S+`.

Comment: You could technically work around the variable-length look-behind limitation by manually expanding the expression `\S+` for every possible length combination - which is only 140, because that's the limit of a tweet: `(?<!@\S{0}|@\S{1}|@\S{2}|@\S{3}|@\S{4}|@\S{5}|@\S{6}|@\S{7}|@\S{8}|@\S{9}|@\S{10}...)y+`: http://www.rubular.com/r/AVQpARNDRf. However there are better ways to approach the problem that have been previously suggested :)

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise There's no need to do that though; Millimoose's suggestion would work fine. Use `(\b@\S+\b)|(<regex for characters you want to replace>)` combined with a `Matcher` and `appendReplacement` to process the matches - ignore any that start with `@`, and alter the others as desired. You'll never accidentally alter a username.

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise, Java's regex do support variable length lookbehinds. And note that `\b@` is probably not what the OP means (`@` is not a word character). I guess he wants `\B@`.

Comment: (?<!\\B@\\S{1,20})y+ worked perfectly.

Comment: @user2149140, I suggest you post that as an answer and accept it, so that the question is answered.

Comment: I'll accept it as soon as I am allowed; it won't let me for another 2 days Thanks for the \B thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text.replaceAll("(?i)(?<!\\B@\\S{1,20})y+", "y");` works. The current version of Java supports variable length lookbefore, so long as it's explicitly less than some maximum length size of look-before.

Since twitter usernames have a fixed maximum length, a fixed maximum on the variable length lookbefore solves the problem.

Comment: +1 I didn't know Java supported variable-length lookbehind. Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
String regEx = "(\\s+[^@\\s]\\S*y+\\S*)|(^[^@\\s]\\S*y+\\S*)";
```